# Kotlin, Firebase Database About its Connection

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pull the data of one of my users in firebase database.
But how can I do that?

[image]

I just want to access the data of the user I marked

```
(enter code here)                            
      mRef.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot!!.getValue()!= null){
                for (user in snapshot.children){
                    var sanMar=user.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    button4.setOnClickListener {
                        textView13.text="${sanMar!!.user_id}"
                        textView14.text="${sanMar!!.adiSoyadi}"
                        textView15.text="${sanMar!!.phoneNumber}"
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you shared? When you run it: what does it do, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: With these codes, I can only reach the most recently added user. But I want to access the information of the user I want or choose.

Comment: for now      "var sanMar=user.getValue(Users::class.java)" I took care of it by adding an if control underneath. but if anyone has a better solution, I am looking forward to it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the UID of the user you want to access, you can directly access that specific user's node (without a query). For example, to access the node for the user who is currently signed in you'd do:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
mRef.child("users").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            var sanMar=snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
            ...
        }
```

In the above scenario, since you're directly accessing the node for one specific user, you don't need to loop over `getChildren()`.

---

If you know *something* about the user, you can use a query to find user nodes that match that condition. Say for example, you know the user name you can filter on that with:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = mRef.child("users");
Query userNameQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("userName").equalTo("kejmekan");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
userNameQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            var sanMar=userSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
            ...
        }
```

Now you **do** need to loop, because the query *could* match multiple child nodes.

---

The above samples are in Java code, but it should be easy enough to convert to Kotlin.

Comment: Code 2 worked for me. Exactly like I want, thank you for helping,.